# Replace all occurrences found by text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to me able to replace all `{{text}}` occurrences by `OOOOO`.

This code works except the replacement.

Could you please help me with that ?

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>{{Titre}} de la pub</title>
</head>

<body>
Contenu et {{compagnie}}
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var a = $("html").html().match(new RegExp("\{\{[^{}]+\}\}", "g"));
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        $("html").html().replace(a[i], 'OOOOO');
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this qualifies for Tony the Pony! You generally shouldn't parse the entire document with a regex.

Comment: [**TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @adeneo - is there a hat for that?

Comment: @j08691 - There should be, an easter egg zalgo hat !

Comment: I'll help you out a little, you're not returning the html anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Agreed you probably shouldn't do the entire document. Maybe use jQuery('p') or similar.

Use .html( new html that you want ) to write the html.

Something like

```
$('p').each(function( i, p) { 
       var $p = $(p); 
       $p.html( $p.html().replace(/some regex/, 'replacement')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, which i think simpler, do what ever you want with the elements

```
$(function() {
    var html = $('html').html();
    $('p').html(html.replace(/{{text}}/gi, '<i>000000</i>'));
}
```